# Cannot get results to show when querying salary of department based on average salary of department and twice minimum salary of entire company

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I am attempting to display the department and average salary of employees in said department if it meets a condition: average salary of department must be twice the minimum salary of the entire firm.

```
select dname, avg(salary) from department, employee where dno=dnumber group by dname having avg(salary) > min(salary)*2;
```

I have tables for employee, department. My query is below, however it results in an empty table.
I believe it is because salary in the halving clause is referencing within department and within employee - or rather it isn't doing this properly.

To just list average salaries by department I used this query which seems to work fine:

```
select dname, avg(salary) from department, employee where dno=dnumber group by dname;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Better use join syntax `from department inner join employee on dno=dnumber`

Comment: @Turo when I do that, while it still works with the change you mentioned below, I get a warning on the "from department": department is disconnected from the rest of join graph: department employee. But also, why better (fairly new to sql so curious)?

Comment: with two tables (and no where clause) its not that important, but when joining 3 or more tables it gives a better understnading of the query, seperating the joining from the where clause and showing explicitly the way of the connections.

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`min(salary)` is the minimum of the department, replace it with `(select min(salary) from employee)`

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I overlooked something so simple. Thanks again!